# Radzen X Axis Format Method

Tags: c#, charts, radzen

X Axis Formatter Method

The user can select a specified DateRange label from a dropdown, which will then dynamically render sales data in between the given range.
The DateRange labels are as follows:
Today or Yesterday
Current Week or Last Week
Current Month or Last Month
Current Year or Last Year

The x axis should be labeled as follows on user selection:
Today or Yesterday (12am - 11:59pm)
Current Week or Last Week (Sun - Mon)
Current Month or Last Month (1 - 30 or 1- 31)
Current Year or Last Year (Jan - Dec)

The code I currently have (Not working):

```
public string FormatXAxis(object value)
        {
            DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)value;

            if (selectedDateRange == "Today")
            {
                DateTime startOfDay = dateTime.Date;
                DateTime endOfDay = startOfDay.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);

                if (dateTime >= startOfDay && dateTime <= endOfDay)
                {
                    return dateTime.ToString("h tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
            }
            else if (selectedDateRange == "Yesterday")
            {
                DateTime startOfYesterday = dateTime.Date.AddDays(-1);
                DateTime endOfYesterday = dateTime.Date.AddTicks(-1);

                if (dateTime >= startOfYesterday && dateTime <= endOfYesterday)
                {
                    return dateTime.ToString("h tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
            }
            else if (selectedDateRange == "Current Week" || selectedDateRange == "Last Week")
            {
                DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = dateTime.DayOfWeek;

                if (dayOfWeek >= DayOfWeek.Monday && dayOfWeek <= DayOfWeek.Thursday)
                {
                    return dateTime.ToString("ddd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
            }
            else if (selectedDateRange == "Current Month" || selectedDateRange == "Last Month")
            {
                return dateTime.ToString("dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else if (selectedDateRange == "Current Year" || selectedDateRange == "Last Year")
            {
                return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(dateTime.Month);
            }
            return string.Empty; // Return empty string if no match
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty example with data showing a range of a day or a week, depending on selected dropdown. Radzen uses for the datetime formatting the official way [Microsoft Custom date and time format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) or a more comfortable example here [Example for date and time format strings](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/datetime-formats-in-csharp?utm_content=cmp-true)

But of course, you still have to edit the period so that not too many values are displayed otherwise they overlap. As an idea you could calculate a factor depending on the amount of elements.
For example if you always want 10 Elements to show on x-axis and you have 50 days you can calculate the timespan = amountofelements / 10 and round it to one decimal place. Then all data would be displayed in the chart and on the x-axis label only every 5th element would be displayed.

This is the c# example

```
public IEnumerable<string> SpanFilter;
public string SelectedSpan;
public List<DataModel> PeriodChartData;
public TimeSpan PeriodStep;
public TimeSpan TotalTimeSpan;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    SpanFilter = new string[] { "Today", "Week" };
    SelectedSpan = SpanFilter.FirstOrDefault();
    OnSelectionChanged();
}

public void OnSelectionChanged()
{
   PeriodChartData = new List<DataModel>();

    var hoursToCount = 23;
    if (SelectedSpan == "Week")
        hoursToCount = 168; 
        
    for (int i = 0; i < hoursToCount; i++)
    {
        var testData = new DataModel()
            {
                DatetimeFrom = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(1) + TimeSpan.FromHours(i),
                DatetimeTo = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(1) + TimeSpan.FromHours(i + 1),
                ExampleData = i
            };
        PeriodChartData.Add(testData);
    }
    TotalTimeSpan = PeriodChartData.Last().DatetimeTo - PeriodChartData.First().DatetimeFrom;
    if (TotalTimeSpan.TotalHours > 24)
        PeriodStep = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    else
        PeriodStep = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);

    StateHasChanged();
}

public class DataModel
{
    public int ExampleData
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public DateTime DatetimeFrom
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public DateTime DatetimeTo
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

This is the blazor code:

```
@if (PeriodChartData != null)
{
   <RadzenChart>
       <RadzenLineSeries Data="@PeriodChartData" Title="Example Data" ValueProperty="ExampleData" CategoryProperty="DatetimeFrom" />

       @if (TotalTimeSpan.TotalHours > 24)
       {
           <RadzenCategoryAxis FormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" Step=@PeriodStep Padding="20" />
       }
       else
       {
           <RadzenCategoryAxis FormatString="{0:HH:mm}" Step=@PeriodStep Padding="20" />
       }
   </RadzenChart>
}
```

If you select the Weekly output

[Screenshot for one week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36AW9.png)

If you select the daily output:

[Screenshot for one day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIM19.png)